# switch between printing configurations in emacs

Tags: emacs, printing, elisp

The default printing in emacs is to print one page per paper with some margins.
I have this function that changes the margins and sets printing to two pages per paper "most numbers are to maximize printing space:

```
(defun ps-two-per-page ()
  (interactive)
  (require 'ps-print)
  (setq ps-n-up-printing    2
    ps-n-up-border-p    nil
    ps-paper-type      'letter
    ps-font-size        (quote (8 . 11))
    ps-top-margin       -20
    ps-bottom-margin    -35
    ps-left-margin      18 
    ps-right-margin     18 
    ps-n-up-margin      1  
    ps-inter-column     1  
    )
  'ps-two-per-page)
```

Once the function executes I will no longer able to go back to the default printing configuration.
How is it possible for me to go back to print using default configuration "as if I did not execute the above command"?

Also, is there way to bind the printing commands in emacs under the "file" drop down menu.
Meaning, I would like to bind "Postscript Print Buffer" to be print using the default configuration, and "Postscript Print Buffer (B+W)" to follow the configuration I have in the above command ps-two-per-page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WRT to first question: while ignoring the details of ps-print, in these cases two strategies are to adopt

1) set variables behind a let

2) store old values with a prefix old-... and reset afterward.

Here a draft of the second way:

```
(defun ps-two-per-page ()
  (interactive)
  (require 'ps-print)
  (setq old-ps-n-up-printing ps-n-up-printing
        old-ps-n-up-border-p ps-n-up-border-p
        old-ps-paper-type ps-paper-type
        old-ps-font-size ps-font-size
        old-ps-top-margin ps-top-margin
        old-ps-bottom-margin ps-bottom-margin
        old-ps-left-margin ps-left-margin
        old-ps-right-margin ps-right-margin
        old-ps-n-up-margin ps-n-up-margin
        old-ps-inter-column ps-inter-column

        ps-n-up-printing 2
        ps-n-up-border-p nil
        ps-paper-type 'letter
        ps-font-size (quote (8 . 11))
        ps-top-margin -20
        ps-bottom-margin -35
        ps-left-margin 18
        ps-right-margin 18
        ps-n-up-margin 1
        ps-inter-column 1))


 (defun ps-restore-default ()
  "Get old values back"
  (interactive)
  (require 'ps-print)
  (setq ps-n-up-printing old-ps-n-up-printing
        ps-n-up-border-p old-ps-n-up-border-p
        ps-paper-type old-ps-paper-type
        ps-font-size old-ps-font-size
        ps-top-margin old-ps-top-margin
        ps-bottom-margin old-ps-bottom-margin
        ps-left-margin old-ps-left-margin
        ps-right-margin old-ps-right-margin
        ps-n-up-margin old-ps-n-up-margin
        ps-inter-column old-ps-inter-column))
```